# Elipses in Spyder IDE - remove

Tags: python, spyder

When working with Spyder IDE, is there a way to expand the information printed to the console? I am trying to return information from `GridSearchCV`, but it is cut off.

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=([(('clf', RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            ...n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False))])
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That's handled by the library you're using (Scikit-learn in this case, right?) and not by Spyder. So I think you need to inform this limitation to the developers of that library.

Comment: Scikit-learn yes. Thanks for that info.